Car chase and a grenade stuffed into a helmet
I can never forget one scene from it, where some guy on a motorcycle is chasing a car full of bad people. Then he gets too close and is partially pulled in the window. As he's wearing a helmet, the people in the car decide to shove a grenade into it and let go of him. Then of course he couldn't get it out in time …
Well you don't forget something like that, even from a movie I guess.
And I watched it about 10 years ago from my room-mate's computer.

Here's an excerpt from a review of Dobermann (1997):

During the heist, they are pursued by a policeman on a motorcycle, they grab the guy off the cycle and into their car, shove grenade into his helmet, toss him out onto the street, and we watch him panic before exploding.

I'd say that's a match.
P.S.  Now that I know the title, it's easy to find the scene on YouTube.
